# how to get json value in android

Tags: java, android, json

I read many example and try it. But it didn't work to get the value.

The result returned a whole JSON to me.

I don't know where is wrong...

This is my first time to ask question. Thanks for help.

Here is my JSON and JAVA Code.

JSON:`

```
{
    "food":{
        "name":"XXX Food",
        "details":{
            "code":"01",
            "location":{
                "area":"Area D",
                "place":"Food"
            },
            "price":"132.21",
            "discount":"15%"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to get the price.

JAVA Code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(recvStr);
            JSONArray Results = json.getJSONArray("food");
            JSONArray msg = Results.getJSONArray(0);

            result = msg.getJSONObject(0).getString("price");
```

Comment: just a thought: if you are making a rest call to get this JSON, then try SPring RestTemplate then use Jackson as message converter to bind your JSON with java model. it will simplify your marshalling /unmarshalling

Answer (score 1):

`Results` is not a `JSONArray` but a `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject results = json.getJSONObject("food");
String name = results.getString("name");
JSONObject details = results.getJSONObject("details");
String price = details.getString("price");
```

You can read more about JSON at [json.org](http://json.org).